# Why isn't my SELinux logging anything?

Tags: logging, selinux, rsyslog

I have a sneaking suspicion it has something to do with me mucking about with my rsyslog.conf, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

I am running Centos 7, and SELinux has been working A-OK. However, I tried to follow [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/909041/42039) and SELinux did not deny.

I did the following:

```
useradd fnord
echo "fnord:user_u:s0-s0:c0.c1023" >> /etc/selinux/targeted/seusers
setsebool user_exec_content off
sudo su - fnord
cp /bin/ls /tmp
/tmp/ls
```

The `/tmp/ls` command worked just fine. I tried with and without the `-P` flag, but it doesn't make any difference.

I'm trying to trigger some SELinux log message, because `/var/audit/audit.log` is empty no matter what I do. I know that SELinux is enforcing things, because rsyslog is setup to send certain logs to `/company/var/log/`, but those logs do not get written. If I change SELinux to permissive instead of enforcing they *do* get written. But nothing writes to `/var/audit/audit.log` anymore. It definitely used to - I have `audit.log.1` and other rolled over files.

I thought initially that it may have been `/etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf`, I had changed the contents from `$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog` to `$SystemLogSocketName /dev/log` but I have since changed it back and restarted rsyslog. And still nothing shows up in `audit.log`.

How can I discover why this doesn't log right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, `kauditd` != `auditd`, and `auditd` is the service that SELinux uses to log with.

When `systemctl start auditd` fails you can look in `/var/log/messages`. In my case, I found that `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (a file I removed and `touch`ed) needs to have `0600` permissions (I think it said `0640` was also OK).

Doing this:

```
# chmod 600 /var/log/audit/audit.log
# systemctl start auditd
```

Re-enabled logging